# Fourier transform of $g(t)=\begin{cases}1-|t|&|t|\leq1,\\~~~~0&\text{everywhere else}\end{cases}$

Tags: fourier-transform

I'm having trouble on how I should work with this particular Fourier transform:

> $$
> g(t)=
> \begin{cases}
> 1-|t| & |t|\leq1,\\
> ~~~~0 &\text{everywhere else}
> \end{cases}
> $$

I understand the integral notation, but I can't seem to reason that any of the Fourier pairs known to me can be used to simplify it.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Maybe you could just compute the Fourier transform directly from the definition?

Comment: That is one way- yes, but in my particular case I'm doing this to end up with a representation of a power spectrum. The function I posted is an autocorrelation function, but it's not relevant to my problem-space at the moment.

Comment: How about the self covolution of $h(t)$, where $h(t)=1$ for $-1/2 \le t \le 1/2$ and $h(t)=0$ elsewhere. Use the property of Fourier transform then.

Comment: I have no idea what you last comment means. No matter what technique you use you will end up with the same result. Why are you posting a function that is not relevant to your problem-space??

Comment: @copper.hat I suppose my wording was poor- the function is indeed relevant to my problem. It is a part of a larger issue that essentially boils down to me finding the simplified Fourier transform of the above g(t).

Comment: I'm just struggling to understand how I should deal with the absolute value of t during my evaluation.

Comment: Split the integral into $[-1,0]$ and $[0,1]$. Or, note that $g$ is even.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f$ denote the characteristic function of the interval $[-1/2, 1/2]$. You can easily check that $g$ is the convolution of $f$ with itself:
$$g(x) = \int_{-1/2}^{1/2}f(y)f(x-y)\ dy = \int_{-1/2}^{1/2}f(x-y)\ dy$$
Consequently, the Fourier transform of $g$ is the product of the Fourier transform of $f$ with itself:
$$\mathcal Fg = (\mathcal Ff)^2$$
It is straightforward to compute $\mathcal Ff$:
$$\begin{aligned}
\mathcal Ff(u) &= \int_{-1/2}^{1/2}f(x)e^{-iux}\ dx \\
&= \int_{-1/2}^{1/2}e^{-iux}\ dx \\
&= \frac{1}{-iu}(e^{-iu/2} - e^{iu/2}) \\
&= \frac{-2i\sin(u/2)}{-iu} \\
&= \frac{\sin(u/2)}{u/2}
\end{aligned}$$
Consequently, 
$$\mathcal Fg(u) = (\mathcal Ff(u))^2 = \left(\frac{\sin(u/2)}{u/2}\right)^2$$

---

Alternatively, you can calculate the Fourier transform directly:
$$\begin{aligned}
\mathcal Fg(u) &= \int_{-1}^{1}g(x) e^{-iux}\ dx \\
&= \int_{-1}^{1}g(x)\cos(ux)\ dx \qquad \text{since $g\cdot \sin$ is odd} \\
&= 2\int_0^{1}g(x)\cos(ux)\ dx \qquad \text{since $g\cdot \cos$ is even} \\
&= 2\int_0^1(1-x)\cos(ux)\ dx \\
&= 2\int_0^1\cos(ux)\ dx - 2\int_0^1 x\cos(ux)\ dx \\
\end{aligned}$$
The first integral is easy:
$$2\int_0^1\cos(ux)\ dx = \frac{2}{u}(\sin(u) - \sin(0)) = \frac{2\sin(u)}{u}$$
The second integral can be evaluated using integration by parts to yield
$$2\int_0^1x\cos(ux)\ dx = \frac{2(u\sin(u)+\cos(u)-1)}{u^2}$$
Therefore, 
$$\begin{aligned}
\mathcal Fg(u) &= \frac{2\sin(u)}{u} - \frac{2(u\sin(u)+\cos(u)-1)}{u^2} \\
&= \frac{2(1 - \cos(u))}{u^2} \\
&= \frac{2(2\sin^2(u/2))}{u^2} \\
&= \frac{\sin^2(u/2)}{(u/2)^2} \\
&= \left(\frac{\sin(u/2)}{u/2}\right)^2
\end{aligned}$$
The first proof is quite a bit less work! Exploit properties such as convolution $\mapsto$ product when you can.

Comment: Thank you so much. I did notice that, because g(x) has a term of 1, can't we let this evaluate to the dirac delta function?

Comment: @questionable_code No, because the term $1$ only applies within the support of $g$ (the interval $[-1,1]$). The function is zero outside this interval.

Comment: Good point. Assuming $ 2 \pi f \ = \ u $ here, how can I rationalize the final answer? I don't generally work with anything as $ \omega $

Comment: You can simply replace $u$ with $2\pi f$ and simplify. You will end up with $$\left(\frac{\sin(\pi f)}{\pi f}\right)^2$$

Comment: Thank you very much. You have been a big help with this issue. I'm going to work through a bit more to make sure I'm good to go. If I am, I'll be sure to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You can split absolute value and work with function
$$
g(t)=
\begin{cases}
1+t & -1\leq t<0 ,\\
1-t & 0\leq t<1 .
\end{cases}
$$
for the Fourier transform of $g(x)$ we see by definition
\begin{align}
{\cal F}(g)
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-i w t}g(t)\,dt \\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\left(\int_{-1}^0 (1+t) e^{-i w t}\, dt + \int_0^1 (1+t) e^{-i w t}\, dt\right) \\
&= \frac{i w+1-e^{i w}}{\sqrt{2\pi}w^2}-\frac{iw-1+e^{-iw}}{\sqrt{2\pi}w^2} \\
&= \dfrac{2}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\dfrac{1-\cos w}{w^2}
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What exactly are a and b here, if I may ask? I think I'm beginning to understand, but I'm not quite there.

Comment: $a_0$, $a_n$ and $b_n$ are Fourier series coefficients, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_series, http://www.sosmath.com/fourier/fourier1/fourier1.html and also http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FourierSeries.html.

Comment: Oh, goodness-- yes, okay. Thank you. The only issue then becomes having a continuous form to present my answer in. I see what you're saying as the answer to my problem being the a summation of all of the cosine terms of the complex, but how can I present this as a concise answer, rather than the expansion of the series?

Comment: I'm sorry. I hastily saw it as Fourier series, but it's Fourier transform :).

Comment: No worries. The conceptual pieces of your answer have been helpful.